# I am running a loop starting from i = 0 but the program starts from i = 2

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sorted = 0;
    int a[10]={10,32,32,4,5,7,2};
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 7)
    {
        printf("%d,",a[i]);
        ++i;
        
    }
    printf("\n");

    i = 0;
    int b;
    i = 0;
    while(sorted != 1)
    {
        i = 0;
        while (i < 7)
        {
            
            sorted = 1;
            if (a[i] > a[i+1])
            {
                printf("%d\n",i);
                printf("%d and %d\n",a[i],a[i+1]);
                b = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = b;
                sorted = 0;
                printf("working\n");
            }
            ++i;
        }
        

    }

    i =0;
    while(i < 7)
    {
        printf("%d,",a[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

here is the code could someone please help me out . the code has a loop that needs to start form i = 0 but the code starts form i = 2 . can someone help me out . the code is based on bubble sorting

Comment: which loop are you referring to?

Comment: Accessing a[i+1] looks dodgy in a loop where i goes up to 6..

Comment: The most nested loop has the condition `if (a[i] > a[i+1])` which doesn't hold for the first two iterations, hence it isn't printing anything.

Comment: General note, if you have assignment, condition and increment / decrement in every repetition of the loop, use for loop instead of while.
make the code more readable in my opinion.

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will either help you solve the problem, or help you write a concise and focused question.

Comment: Note: you can rewrite all your `where()` loops into `for()` loops. This wil make your program 8 lines shorter. It would also become easier to read and verify.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing `i` only when you are swapping and in your first iteration swapping started only after 2nd index.

Also, your inner while loop should only do i<6 because you only have 7 elements and you are looking for a i+1.

Answer (score 1):

This question is an example of the programmer's laziness.

Add some `printf`s and debug.

```
int main(void)
{
    int sorted = 0;
    int a[10]={10,32,32,4,5,7,2};
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 7)
    {
        printf("a[%d] == %d%s",i, a[i], i == 6 ? "\n" : ", ");
        ++i;
        
    }
    printf("\n");

    i = 0;
    int b;
    i = 0;
    while(sorted != 1)
    {
        i = 0;
        while (i < 7)
        {
            printf("Loop: i == %d, a[i] > a[i+1] == %d\n",i, a[i] > a[i+1]);
            sorted = 1;
            if (a[i] > a[i+1])
            {
                printf("\t(Inside if) i = %d\n",i);
                printf("\t(Inside if) a[%d]==%d and a[%d] ==%d\n",i, a[i], i + 1, a[i+1]);
                b = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i+1];
                a[i+1] = b;
                printf("\t\tAfter Swap: a[] = ");
                for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
                {
                    printf("%d%s", a[x], x == 6 ? "\n" : ", ");          
                }
                sorted = 0;
                printf("\t(Inside if() working\n");
            }
            ++i;
        }
        

    }

    i =0;
    while(i < 7)
    {
        printf("a[%d] == %d%s",i, a[i], i==6 ? "\n" : ", ");
        ++i;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vvEcfEa3f

And the output will say something about your code behaviour:

```
a[0] == 10, a[1] == 32, a[2] == 32, a[3] == 4, a[4] == 5, a[5] == 7, a[6] == 2

Loop: i == 0, a[i] > a[i+1] == 0
Loop: i == 1, a[i] > a[i+1] == 0
Loop: i == 2, a[i] > a[i+1] == 1
    (Inside if) i = 2
    (Inside if) a[2]==32 and a[3] ==4
        After Swap: a[] = 10, 32, 4, 32, 5, 7, 2
    (Inside if() working
Loop: i == 3, a[i] > a[i+1] == 1
    (Inside if) i = 3
    (Inside if) a[3]==32 and a[4] ==5
        After Swap: a[] = 10, 32, 4, 5, 32, 7, 2
    (Inside if() working
Loop: i == 4, a[i] > a[i+1] == 1
    (Inside if) i = 4
    (Inside if) a[4]==32 and a[5] ==7
        After Swap: a[] = 10, 32, 4, 5, 7, 32, 2
    (Inside if() working
Loop: i == 5, a[i] > a[i+1] == 1
    (Inside if) i = 5
    (Inside if) a[5]==32 and a[6] ==2
        After Swap: a[] = 10, 32, 4, 5, 7, 2, 32
    (Inside if() working
Loop: i == 6, a[i] > a[i+1] == 1
    (Inside if) i = 6
    (Inside if) a[6]==32 and a[7] ==0
        After Swap: a[] = 10, 32, 4, 5, 7, 2, 0
    (Inside if() working
Loop: i == 0, a[i] > a[i+1] == 0
Loop: i == 1, a[i] > a[i+1] == 1
    (Inside if) i = 1
    (Inside if) a[1]==32 and a[2] ==4
        After Swap: a[] = 10, 4, 32, 5, 7, 2, 0
    (Inside if() working
Loop: i == 2, a[i] > a[i+1] == 1
    (Inside if) i = 2
    (Inside if) a[2]==32 and a[3] ==5
        After Swap: a[] = 10, 4, 5, 32, 7, 2, 0
    (Inside if() working
Loop: i == 3, a[i] > a[i+1] == 1
    (Inside if) i = 3
    (Inside if) a[3]==32 and a[4] ==7
        After Swap: a[] = 10, 4, 5, 7, 32, 2, 0
    (Inside if() working
Loop: i == 4, a[i] > a[i+1] == 1
    (Inside if) i = 4
    (Inside if) a[4]==32 and a[5] ==2
        After Swap: a[] = 10, 4, 5, 7, 2, 32, 0
    (Inside if() working
Loop: i == 5, a[i] > a[i+1] == 1
    (Inside if) i = 5
    (Inside if) a[5]==32 and a[6] ==0
        After Swap: a[] = 10, 4, 5, 7, 2, 0, 32
    (Inside if() working
Loop: i == 6, a[i] > a[i+1] == 0
a[0] == 10, a[1] == 4, a[2] == 5, a[3] == 7, a[4] == 2, a[5] == 0, a[6] == 32
```

Comment: Thank you so much man . You just saved me